# mongoose Namespace has no exported member 'OptionalId'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error while i run npm i.

../@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:191:17 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/test-service/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index"' has no exported member 'OptionalId'  ? mongodb.OptionalId & { _id: TId }>

I am using "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.32", "@types/mongodb": "~3.3.1".  Can someone help me solving this problem. my tsc version is Version 3.8.3 .

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just solved the problem by running this command.

```
npm install --save @types/mongodb
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Instead of `--save` flag use `-D` this will save it as a Dev Dependency so you won't install types in your production bundle.

Answer (score 2):

## Why  ?

my project node_modules like this,

- node_modules

  - @types/mongoose/@types/mongodb
  - @types/mongodb

**@types/mongoose** has **@types/mongodb** dependencie, and it has **conflict** with **@types/mongodb**.

## How to Fix

Run this command at your node_modules directory:

$ **rm -rf node_modules/@types/mongoose/node_modules/@types/mongodb**

Done.

Hope to help someone.